# BAN url with get parameters in Varnish

Tags: regex, pcre, varnish

I'm having a problem to ban a url inside Varnish (Version 6.0.2).

I'm trying to ban a url like this

```
/api/v2/product?param1=value1&param2=value2param3=value3
```

If I give this command:

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product'
```

It works correctly but it bans all the urls that start with `/api/v2/product` and I need to ban just that specific url.

These are the tries that I've done:

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product?param1=value1&param2=value2param3=value3'
```

It doesn't return any error but it doesn't ban the url

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product\?param1=value1'
```

and I get this error:

```
Unknown request.
Type 'help' for more info.
Syntax Error: Invalid backslash sequence

Command failed with error code 100
```

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product[?]param1=value1'
```

or

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product\\?param1=value1'
```

It doesn't return any error but it doesn't ban the url

I've tried also without the Regex using the `==`

```
varnishadm ban req.url '==' '/api/v2/product?param1=value1&param2=value2param3=value3'
```

It doesn't return any error but it doesn't ban the url

I thought that the problem was the `?` so I tried to use the `.*` instead of the `?`

I've tried:

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product.*param1=value1'
```

And it works, it bans all the urls that start with: `^/api/v2/product&param1=value1` so I've tried

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product.*param1=value1&param2=value2'
```

It doesn't return any error but it doesn't ban the url, so I supected that the problem could be the `&` this time so I've tried:

```
varnishadm ban req.url '~' '^/api/v2/product.*param1=value1.*param2=value2'
```

But nothing, it doesn't return errors but it doesn't ban that url.

Any attempt to escape the special character using the \ returns the error message:

```
Unknown request.
Type 'help' for more info.
Syntax Error: Invalid backslash sequence

Command failed with error code 100
```

Varnish manual says that the software uses PCRE standards, but I can't find a way to write a regex for it.

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks
H2K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, there was a

```
set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);
```

inside the code that was altering the order of my get parameters invalidating the regex.